# Need some jQuery to remove an <a> tag with an empty href

Tags: jquery

I've tried a couple times but can't seem to figure out how to write a simple piece of jQuery to remove an  tag if the href is empty. Here is the string I need to remove.

```
<a id="single_image" href="">Zoom</a>
```

Any suggestions?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Gumbo's answer is the easiest to implement. If you want more control over the actual href you can use something like this:

```
$("a").each(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    if(href == '') { // or anything else you want to remove...
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

This will loop through all `<a>` tags and get you the actual href so you can compare it with empty hrefs but can also make sure the href is well-formed, etc.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
$("a[href='']").remove()
```